# Wifi Receiver not triggered Android 4.x.x works on 2.2.1

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Ive created a wifi broadcastreceiver to check for wifi state changes.

This app runs fine on Android 2.2.1 device but does not receive broadcast on 4.x.x devices, I have tested on a 4.1.1 and android 4.4.2 device, no luck? I must be missing something small here. Thanks in advance!

---

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.wifi.test.testapp">

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <receiver android:name=".WifiReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

    <!-- wifi -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
</manifest>
```

---

**.WifiReceiver class**

```
public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "WifiReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "WifiReceiver");
        NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);
    }
}
```

---

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 16
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
    <receiver
      android:name=".WifiReceiver"
      android:exported="false" >`enter code here`
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: what do i enter here? android:exported="false" >`enter code here

Comment: here is what i have in my receiver now, <receiver android:name=".WifiReceiver" android:exported="false" > No luck, still the same result, noting gets received

Answer (score 0):

Prior to API 3.1 we could have a broadcast receiver which could have been invoked by an implicit intent even if the application to which it belonged was in stopped state.
But this posed a security threat. Hence **Google made it mandatory that for any broadcast receiver to receive an intent, there should be an activity and the application should not be in stopped state**.

When an application is launched, it is in stopped state and hence it mandates the user to activate the application which has the broadcast receiver. If the application is force stopped by the user, then again the broadcast receiver fails to receive the intent. Hence apk having only broadcast receiver and developed on version prior to 3.1 will no longer work for later versions.
However one can make use of FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES to activate components in stopped application. This will not require creation of another activity in order to use the broadcast receiver.

---

So I just need to add an activity for the broadcast receiver to work.